# Downloading docx files in Ruby loses its read-only property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a peace of code to make a '.docx' file read-only, saved as an attribute of a model:

```
attachment.file = File.open(path)
attachment.save!
FileUtils.chmod('ugo=r', attachment.file.path)
```

It is saved normally, read-only. But when I download the file, it loses the read-only property, and I can edit the file normally. Is there any way I can make it read-only even after downloaded?

Thanks!

Comment: *"Is there any way I can make it read-only even after downloaded?"* - why do you want to do that?

Comment: Because the file should not be modified. Maybe the solution would be convert it to pdf?

Comment: "should not be modified" -- or what? What can happen otherwise?

Comment: @JesseMignac what kind of file is that?

Comment: It was actualy a '.docx' file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can't.

File itself is only a blob of data. A thing as "read-only flag" is provided by the file system. Web servers convey no information about the underlying file system, so the client can have any file system on his machine – even the one that doesn't support a "read-only" flag at all (I'm not aware of any, but it is theoretically possible).

Even if hypothetically you were able to transmit "read-only" flag over HTTP download, that flag can always be removed by the client system's administrator (i. e. client, most of the time).

You can't prevent users from modifying sent files. **Converting to PDF won't help, [they can actually be edited too](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/how-to/pdf-editor-pdf-files.html)**, albeit with more effort than DOCX and more potential to break formatting.

So as-is it can't be done at all. However, workarounds may be possible for your specific case.

**You could sign the file with a digital signature**, [Microsoft Office offers this functionality](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Add-or-remove-a-digital-signature-in-Office-documents-49af4304-bfe7-41bf-99c3-a5023bdab44a). In an event it gets modified, the signature will become invalid or be removed (depending on the editor used). So the readers will open a file and will have no way to tell if the file is actually written by you.

However, to make sure the file was not altered in the process of transmission, one has to check the signature. If file contents change, the check will fail. If the signature is removed, it won't be there: readers will have to know that it should be.

Signatures are available for a variety of formats that is not limited to MS Office documents. PDFs can be signed as well, if you will. Other formats may require distributing the signature separately.

Answer (score 2):

As you suggested, the best approach would be to change the original file to a format that will most likely not be edited by the user (such as PDF, which can be edited but is considered the norm when you want to give a user a file to be consulted and not edited).

Once your file leave your server, you have to assume that anyone can alter it, there is no way to enforce that they won't be able to since they are now owners of that file.

Comment: Got it. Thanks, dude!

Comment: @JesseMignac no problem! :)

Comment: The truth is, PDF's [**can be edited**](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/how-to/pdf-editor-pdf-files.html).

Comment: @D-side fair point, I will edit my answer to point toward the fact that PDFs are less likely to be altered by your clients but can definitely be edited if you have the means.

Answer (score 1):

You mean that you fetch the file from the web and it should be read-only? It is impossible.

Also it makes no sense as user can easily add read flag to it.